# Can’t get messages posted in the past when using SendBird

Tags: api, sdk, chat, sendbird

- We create a channel using the SendBird server API and invite two users
- User A joins the channel and posts a few messages
- User B joins the channel, but cannot see User A’s messages.

It seems users don't see messages posted before they joined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on "Display Past Message" option in SendBird Dashboard http://dashboard.sendbird.com.

Application -> Settings -> "Display Past Message"